# Delete linebreaks from end of cell while retaining formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have several worksheets across a number of workbooks with hundreds of text cells. The worksheets need to be formatted nicely for printing. Some of these cells have linebreaks, sometimes more than one, at the end of the cell. When I autosize the rows (using a macro), the autosize takes these linebreaks into account and there is sizeable whitespace, which is unacceptable for printing.

I need to somehow perform a search inside each cell starting from the bottom of the cell and delete any linebreaks if there are any (CHR(10), vbCrLf, etc.) but **only until the first non-linebreak character is reached and nowhere else in the cell.**

I cannot use replace(), trim(), or similar functions as the cells contain important formatting, which will be lost by these functions.

For example:

> This is my text.
>
> vbCrLf
>
> This is **bolded**.
>
> vbCrLf
>
> This is *italicized*.
>
> vbCrLf
>
> vbCrLf

I need the last two vbCrLf's at the end of the cell to be deleted, the formatting of the bolded and italicized text to be retained, and no other vbCrLfs in the cell to be deleted.

I have searched far and wide for suitable answers, but have not found one which addresses all my needs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to modify a cell's content without affecting any text formatting is to use the `Characters` collection:

```
Sub RemoveTrailingLineBreaks()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        Do While Right(c.Value, 1) = vbLf Or Right(c.Value, 1) = vbCr
            c.Characters(Len(c.Value), 1).Delete
        Loop
    Next c
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** There's no tidy work-around to the >255 length issue when working with the `Characters` collection.  This is pretty clunky and slow, but does work:

```
Sub Tester()
    RemoveTrailingLineBreaks Range("A1")
End Sub


Sub RemoveTrailingLineBreaks(r As Range)

    Dim info()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, txt

    Set r = Range("A1") '<< long formatted text with trailing linebreaks

    txt = r.Value
    Do While Right(txt, 1) = vbLf Or Right(txt, 1) = vbCr
        txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1)
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    If n = 0 Then Exit Sub 'exit if no trailing new lines
    ReDim info(1 To Len(txt), 1 To 4)
    'collect the format info...
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        With r.Characters(i, 1).Font
            info(i, 1) = .Bold
            info(i, 2) = .Italic
            info(i, 3) = .Size
            info(i, 4) = .Color
        End With
    Next i

    r.Value = txt
    're-apply format info...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        With r.Characters(i, 1).Font
            .Bold = info(i, 1)
            .Italic = info(i, 2)
            .Size = info(i, 3)
            .Color = info(i, 4)
        End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly if the cell is under 255 characters, but most of my cells are above this limit, giving me a run-time error of "Method 'Delete' of object 'Characters' failed."  Can .Characters.Delete be used on cells with more than 255 characters, or is there a workaround here?

Comment: Sorry I meant to include something about that that limitation but was having problems finding a definitive reference.  I'm not sure if there's a workaround.  Posting a new question with this specific issue might get you one.

Comment: I've been playing around with this code to try to get it work with a large range:    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Range("C1:C50")
    Set r = Range("C1:C50") 
    For Each r In cel (etc.)   -      
I am running out of memory when I increase the range however, is what I'm trying to achieve basically a hopeless endeavor?

Comment: How much text is in the cells?

Comment: Up to 2,000 characters in a cell in a range of 300 cells across 3 columns. I might just have to check and do this all manually, as the limitations on what I want to achieve seem to be too big

Comment: Just tested with 2k characters per cell and Yes it's pretty unworkable....